# php foreach behaviour with unset()

Tags: php

if you foreach an array and unset an element inside it, then calling current() on the original array returns FALSE.Can someone please clarify this behavior to me.

```
$locales = array(
0 => 'EN',
1 => 'DE',
2 => 'AR'
);
foreach($locales as $key => $code){
if($code == 'DE'){
    unset($locales[$key]);
}
}

var_dump(current($locales)); // bool(false)
```

PS: Am php noob and programming generally.

Comment: [Can't reproduce your problem](https://3v4l.org/gGZkb) But there will be some changes to the foreach behaviour in PHP 7: http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.foreach

Comment: Working fine for me it return `string(2) "AR"` !!

Comment: It's working fine. But what's the meaning doing var_dump(current($locates))  after iterating whole array?  var_dump(end($locales)) is same thing for Your code

Comment: sorry guys. this is not a problem with php at all. it was a piece code [not shown here] that modified the array pionter, and resulted to  current() returning false. I told you am serious noob :)

Comment: @Saty if i was passing  `$locales` as function argument would `var_dump` still output `string(2) "AR" `. am just curious

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem either. Is it a PHP version issue? I'm using PHP 5.5.9 print_r your array after deletion to see what happened to it :\

Comment: anyway, removing array items during an iteration is generally a bad idea.

Comment: i sensed it. php foreach has silent behaviors

Answer (score 0):

I do not see question in Your post....

And about what You have described, it is kind of strange behaviour in PHP 5.2.4 and maybe some other versions, as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php#116128).

In current versions problem does not seems to occure.